# jqGrid with AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jqgrid

I have been searching for a good example of how to use jqGrid with AngularJS. 
I am aware about the ngGrid and other AngularJS supported grid controls but unfortunately I have an overall theme worked out based on the jqGrid.

I have recently started Angular, so please excuse my noob 'ness.

1) I can fetch data from my server api inside the controller using $http.get. No issues.
2) The jqGrid samples that I have come across all use jquery based ajax calls to fetch the data and bind to the grid. Which I do not want to do unless you experts here tell me that its okay.
3) The other option I thought was to call the controller method on $document.load() and assign the results to the grid control, and continue with the jqGrid initialisation. But what difference does it make from fetching the data using jquery ajax?

Thank you very much for all your answers.

Answer (score 2):

Currently I'm working on a set of angularjs directives for working with jqGrid component. 
The project is open sourced and you could find it on github https://github.com/9ci/angle-grinder
Here is a short documentation how to use grid directive http://9ci.github.io/angle-grinder/docs/#docs-gridz I hope it will be useful.

This project is in early alpha version so any pull requests, issues and ideas are welcome ;)