# Create full jqGrid directive in AngularJS

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid in my application, but I want to make its angularjs directive with jqgrid native features too.

I have made directive as

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('ngJqGrid', function () {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {
    config: '=',
    data: '=',
  },
  link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    var table;

    scope.$watch('config', function (newValue) {
      element.children().empty();
      table = angular.element('<table></table>');
      element.append(table);
      $(table).jqGrid(newValue);
    });

    scope.$watch('data', function (newValue, oldValue) {
      var i;
      for (i = oldValue.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        $(table).jqGrid('delRowData', i);
      }
      for (i = 0; i < newValue.length; i++) {
        $(table).jqGrid('addRowData', i, newValue[i]);
      }
    });
  }
};
});
```

Please refer to plnkr link http://plnkr.co/edit/50dagqDV2hWE2UxG9Zjo?p=preview

But I also need edit and delete buttons in each row along with their functionality.

Please guide me, how do I can achieve this. :(

Comment: For further reference: better use a native Angular implementation of a grid. For example http://ui-grid.info/. No jQuery used

Comment: @Mazzu Where you able to achieve the directive?

Comment: @MárioMeyrelles, not yet :(

Comment: in fairness, It might be worth mentioning that "your code" was actually "borrowed" from the user @words-like-jared from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19433650/angularjs-and-jqgrid

Answer (score 0):

I im working on this if you want to colaborate!
[ngGrid](https://github.com/mijaelcohen/ngGrid)